# Manual Approval for a specefic customer Group

Tags: magento2, customer

I use **Magepelza Customer Approval** for new customers, I have 3 groups, **General B2C, Instalers  and Reselers.**
I would like to let B2C customers Group to login without manual Approval, the others have to be approved manually by the Admin.
Someone have dealed with this scenario before? do you know some extension that I can install?
Thank you!